# Dmha/octodrine legality in europe, preferably in latvia but generally in europe would give a good picture

Tags: medical

Its a fat burner/stim a couple of years ago was widely available in pre workouts/fat burners but i havent seen in in a while.

Alternative names are
Ottodrina; Vaporpac; Amidrine; 2-Amino-6-methylheptane; 1,5-Dimethylhexylamine; 6-Methyl-2-heptylamine; 6-Methyl-2-heptanamine.

Im personally from latvia but i think that EU laws would give a good picture on the legality of this thing

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Octodrine+legal

Comment: No usefull info there. I know its banned in professional sports and military, but that gives no knowledge about importation and posession

Comment: check the local FDA equivalent - they tell you if it is a legal medicine and against what they allow it.

Comment: There is a hudge legal document outlining flat out banned and controlled drugs aswell as formulations and analogues of less known drugs but due to me not being a chemist i cant be 100% shure.

Comment: Ive checked it to the best if my abilities but thougth someone knew for sure, like on example of other eu countries

Answer (score 0):

Such Information can be obtained from the executive body regulating drugs in your country. For the US, that's the FDA, for New Zeeland it's [Medsafe](https://www.medsafe.govt.nz/profs/class/Agendas/Agen63/MCC63_72c_octodrine.pdf). The later also notes:

> Medsafe has received advice that octodrine is a medicine as it is only added to products for a
> therapeutic effect, despite any absence of therapeutic purpose claims for the finished product. There
> does not seem to be any other reason for octodrine to be added to the product other than for a
> therapeutic effect

This means that Medsafe regards any product with it as a medical product. They also tell about some other jurisdictions:

> Australia - In October 2017 the TGA included entries for “DMBA and other aliphatic alkylamines with
> stimulant properties including DMHA”, into Schedule 10 of the Poisons Standard.
>
> USA - The FDA website includes warnings regarding DMAA, DMBA, and β-Methylphenethylamine
> (BMPEA) in dietary supplements. None of these substances have been determined to meet its
> statutory definition of a dietary ingredient.
>
> Canada - DHMA is known as “octodrine and its salts” and is listed as prohibited on the Health Canada
> Cosmetic Ingredient list.
>
> World Anti-Doping Agency (WADA) - octodrine is a prohibited substance in sports competitions under
> class S6 of the Prohibited List.

I can't source a Latvian source due to my lack of ability to speak and read Latvian.